How to use SqlBinaryValue to extract BLOB field as an InputStream in Spring 6.2.0+
Before Spring 6.2.0 this is the code we used to extract a BLOB field as an InputStream:
final LobHandler lobHandler = new DefaultLobHandler();
try (InputStream in = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, params,
        (rs, rowNum) -> lobHandler.getBlobAsBinaryStream(rs, column.getName()))) {
    // Do something with the inputstream
} catch (final DataAccessException e) {
    // Handle the exception
}

After updating to 6.2.0 the classes LobHandler and DefaultLobHandler are deprecated in favor of SqlBinaryValue, however this new class doesn't have a function to extract a BLOB as an InputStream, so I assume we have to use something else.
Any ideas how to migrate this code to the newer classes? I have been checking the Spring tests github but they don't have anything like this.
Thanks.
